# How to create numbered list dynamically in odt file, using JODRepots?

Tags: java, odt

I've got an odt template file, at the moment looking something like this:

```
 ${heading}


 ${documentDate}

                        1. ${orderedList}
```

Filling the heading and documentDate is easy, using a hashmap. My javacode looks like this:

```
public class CreateODF {

public boolean createODF() {
    try {
        DocumentTemplateFactory documentTemplateFactory = new DocumentTemplateFactory();
        DocumentTemplate template = documentTemplateFactory.getTemplate(new File("/tmp/template.odt"));
        Map<String, Object> dataModel = createDataModel();
        template.createDocument(dataModel, new FileOutputStream("/tmp/result.odt"));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return false;
}

public static Map<String, Object> createDataModel() {
    Map<String, Object> dataModel = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    dataModel.put("heading", "Some heading");
    dataModel.put("documentDate", "03.03.2015");
    dataModel.put("orderedList", "Element one\nElement two\nElement three");
    return dataModel;
}
```

}

Result is like this:

```
 Some heading


 03.03.2015

                        1. Element one
                           Element two
                           Element three
```

I'd like it to handle the enumeration automagically. Is this possible? I've googled and looked at examples, but could not find an answer to this..